# Repeating columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

What is the right way of repeating columns in DataFrame?

I'm working on df:

```
  England    Germany    US
0 -3.3199    -3.31      496.68
1 1004.0     4.01       4.01
2 4.9794     4.97       1504.97
3 3.1766     2003.17    3.17
```

And I'd like to obtain:

```
  England  England   Germany  Germany   US        US    
0 -3.3199  -3.3199   -3.31    -3.31     496.68    496.68    
1 1004.0   1004.0    4.01     4.01      4.01      4.01 
2 4.9794   4.9794    4.97     4.97      1504.97   1504.97
3 3.1766   3.1766    2003.17  2003.17   3.17      3.17
```

I tough of getting headers from the original DataFrame and double them:

```
headers_double = [x for x in headers for i in range(2)]
```

Subsequently I tried to create df with new headers:

```
df.columns = [x for x in headers_double]
```

Unfortunately, my way of thinking was wrong. Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have a few columns and you can name them manually, just select columns from your dataframe duplicating those names.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO('''\
  England    Germany    US
0 -3.3199    -3.31      496.68
1 1004.0     4.01       4.01
2 4.9794     4.97       1504.97
3 3.1766     2003.17    3.17
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

print(df[['England', 'England', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'US', 'US']])
```

Output:

```
     England    England  Germany  Germany       US       US
0    -3.3199    -3.3199    -3.31    -3.31   496.68   496.68
1  1004.0000  1004.0000     4.01     4.01     4.01     4.01
2     4.9794     4.9794     4.97     4.97  1504.97  1504.97
3     3.1766     3.1766  2003.17  2003.17     3.17     3.17
```

If you want to do this more generally, you can get your column names, duplicate them and then select columns. The following results in the same output as above:

```
print(df[[col for col in df.columns for i in range(2)]])
```

Comment: I simplified the problem. I have to many columns to do it by hand.

Comment: Check my latest edit, which addresses duplicating all columns programatically instead of manually.

Comment: Thank you so much, dude!

Answer (score 5):

I just came up with another solution that I want to share. Maybe it will be useful for somebody else.

```
print(df[np.repeat(df.columns.values,2)])
```

Comment: I tried this but column index remains the same as the original column , am I missing a trick?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to replicate all columns or replace ':' with a selected range of columns:

df[df.columns[:].append(df.columns)]